# Hovering the button makes appear div. How to make the button stay hovered while being on the appeared div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I let the button stay hovered (background: red) while my mouse is on the appeared div (.menu)?

https://jsfiddle.net/on5Lfmoo/

**HTML**

```
<button class="logo">
  a
</button>

<div class="menu">
  aaa
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  width: 240px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(10,10,10,0.2);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: linear 0.5s;
}

.logo:hover {
  background: red;
 }

.logo:hover + .menu, .menu:hover {
  transform: translateX(0px);
 }
```

Comment: You will need to use javascript

Comment: This would be best achieved with jQuery instead. Even a simple `toggleClass` function would serve you well here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use javascript or jQuery.

Here's a working fiddle of what you were trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/on5Lfmoo/1/

Here's the code:

```js
$('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
 $('.holder').addClass('open');
});
$('.holder').mouseleave(function(){
 $('.holder').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  width: 240px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(10,10,10,0.2);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: linear 0.5s;
}

.open .logo {
  background: red;
 }

.open .menu {
  transform: translateX(0px);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <button class="logo">
    a
  </button>
  <div class="menu">
    aaa
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :)